# How can I get the admin edit user url key for a specific user if I have the user_id and account info, what are the classes/methods for di?

Tags: magento2, admin, di, admin-user, viewmodel

Example:

http://localhost/admin/admin/user/edit/user_id/5/key/db1082c352e51cfb817ce0335dd060cf6e953568daf2da25cca24eadb04dc884/

I want to return 'db1082c352e51cfb817ce0335dd060cf6e953568daf2da25cca24eadb04dc884' from within a ViewModel method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to implement this with View Model you need to use `Magento\Framework\UrlInterface`

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Acme\StackExchange\ViewModel\Adminhtml;

use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Block\ArgumentInterface;

class UrlHelper implements ArgumentInterface
{
    protected UrlInterface $urlBuilder;

    public function __construct(UrlInterface $urlBuilder)
    {
        $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
    }

    public function getUrl(string $route = '', array $params = []): string
    {
        return $this->urlBuilder->getUrl($route, $params);
    }

    public function getAdminUserViewUrl(int $userId): string
    {
        return $this->getUrl('adminhtml/user/edit', ['user_id' => $userId]);
    }
}
```

Using

```
$viewModel->getAdminUserViewUrl((int)$userId);
```